# Sending notification from google spreadsheet using time-driven events with condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to receive notifications when domain will expire. So I created a spreadsheet with a list of website and date of expiration. It has also a condition in `Column A` that when a domain is about to expire in 10 days it will appear `Send notification` as cell value. You can view my spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ujML0JxwkFdk5aqJSLuudK3MuDfUOezpTPflHGHGRys/edit?usp=sharing).

With the values in `column A`, I would like to receive emails telling that the `www.sample.com` will expire on `--some date here--`.

For example, when **Column A** have **new** values equal to `Send notification`, then send email.

What I have tried and encountered:

```
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow(); 
var cellvalue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
var recipients = "youremail@gmail.com";

var domain = '';
var expirydate= '';

if(cell.indexOf('A')!=-1 && cell.indexOf('A') == 'Send notification'){ 
   domain = sheet.getRange('B'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
        expirydate = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
 }      

var subject = 'Expiry Notification : '+sheet.getName();
var body = 'Website will expire! ' + domain + ' is about to expire on ' + expirydate;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
Logger.log(body);
```

Trying this script only sends me notification without the value of the cell.

I would like this works even when the spreadsheet is not open / I am offline. So I guess I will be using the time driven event (every week).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Removed the Excel tag, since this question is not about Excel at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare yourself, my answers tend to be long and explanatory.

Take this block:

```
if(cell.indexOf('A')!=-1 && cell.indexOf('A') == 'Send notification'){ 
   domain = sheet.getRange('B'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
        expirydate = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
 }
```

In this block we can see that the `if` will **always** return `FALSE`. That is because `cell.indexOf('A')` cannot be a string, it will be an integer of the index. You want to be checking the value. I assume that is why you have the `cellvalue` variable.

Furthermore, your use of `getRange()` is also off. Why bother with `A1` notation if you are getting indexes anyway. Instead I will go over the code and offer a different way of coding this.

---

Ok, let's start from the top of the code. You mentioned that you want this to run offline. We immediately get a problem here:

```
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
```

this will be meaningless once you fire script based on a timer. I would recommend batching your data collection. First to be sure that you are not using `getActiveSheet()`:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Send notification')
```

OR

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]
```

to get the first sheet or the sheet by it's name. Then we get the entire list into a 2D array.

```
var vals = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
```

So we wish to check all domains. So now that we have all the values we wish to loop through them (we assume we left `var domain` and `var expirydate` as is)

```
var i
for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  if (vals[i][0] == 'Send notification!') {
    domain = vals[i][1] //we get the domain name.
    expirydate = vals[i][3] //we get the expire date
    sendNotification(domain, expirydate); //use a seperate fu
  }
}
```

where in the above block code I would seperate the function

```
function sendNotification(domain, expirydate) {
  var subject = 'Expiry Notification : '+ domain;
  var body = 'Website will expire! ' + domain + ' is about to expire on ' + expirydate;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  Logger.log(body);
}
```

of course you can leave the code inside of the `for` loop, but this will look cleaner. Also, I am not sure you really wanted `var subject = 'Expiry Notification : '+sheet.getName();` because that will send all emails with the title **Expiry Notification : Send notification** because that is the sheet name (the tab at the bottom of the spreadsheet)